# Execution time of a while loop in Arduino Due doesn't match what expected

Tags: time, arduino

I wrote the following infinite loop consisting principally of five high-level instructions and ran it on an Arduino Due. Assuming one clock cycle per instruction I was expecting the LED to flash about every 5/6 second. Instead the time is above 30 seconds. Is there something slowing down the execution of this code?

```cpp
#define LED_PIN     13
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);    
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  noInterrupts();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void loop()
{   
  int cnt = 0;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  noInterrupts();

  while(true) // infinite loop
  {    
    if(cnt == 0)  // if cnt == 0 turn off led
    {
        interrupts();
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);    
        noInterrupts();
    } 
    // clock rate 84000000 cycles per second
    if(cnt == VARIANT_MCK) // if cnt is equal to clock rate flash on led 
    {
      interrupts();
      delay(10);    
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);  
      delay(10);   // turn on led for a small amount of time 
      noInterrupts();
      cnt = - 1; // reset counter
    }  

    cnt ++ ; // increment counter
  }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Did you count conditions? Did you check assembler code?

Answer (score 0):

I were expecting the number of seconds roughly shows, how many clock ticks it takes to do

```
while (true) {
  cnt++;
  if (cnt == 0) {/* signalTheStart(); */}
  if (cnt == VARIANT_MCK) {/* signalTheEnd(); */}
}
```

One 32-bit int increment, two failing int comparisons, and a jump back.

Not sure how often the variable is moved to / from memory and how a comparison with a 32 bit constant (?) is actually performed, and I do not know the ARM internals. But I agree, 30 ticks is a bit more than I expected. I guess by `5/6`you mean "five or six" and not a bit less than one, but both interpretations are too optimistic.

Michael Zhilin's hint "Check assembler code" from the compiled binary is the way to go...

And, why do you need that? You already noticed that you need to inhibit interrupts, so this measurement is not applicable to real world scenarios at all...

Answer (score 0):

Writing the code in assembler solved the problem. By comparing the on-off period of the led, the compiler generate about ten time the instructions i wrote directly in assembler.